# Dual Rail Reverse Protection Circuit for OP AMP inputs

Tags: operational-amplifier, protection, short-circuit

[image: When polarity is correct, vout + and - looks okay.]

[image: When polarity is incorrect, circuit is still conductive and indicators are ON state]

Is there a way to resolve this? When wrong polarities is applied,then I wanted no voltage or current flowing towards the OP Amp. Thanks!!

Comment: Your circuit should work as shown. You MAY have the two FETs swapped. || The voltage drop when on suggests that the FETS are OFF but the body diodes are conducting. Note the connection of the FETS - the drain and source are swapped compared to normal use. High side should be P channel - and the [IRF9530 ](https://rocelec.widen.net/view/pdf/pggrxej88f/HRISSD80-1.pdf?t.download=true&u=5oefqw) is. Your results suggest that you have the N channel FET in the high side with source towards Vin. ie FETs swapped AND D & S wrongly connected.

Comment: Change your zeners to 10V. The current 3.9V ones are marginal compared to the FET's Vgsth. Report bak.

Comment: Also ... :-). [Those FETS](https://rocelec.widen.net/view/pdf/pggrxej88f/HRISSD80-1.pdf?t.download=true&u=5oefqw)  are a very bad choice. They have around 0.25 Ohm on resistance. Far far better ones are available. That should not matter too much at lower currents.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: NB!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! - You should not be using a 741 unless there is an exceptionally special application and device specific reason to be doing so. The 741 was introduced in 1969 - over 50 years ago. It was a superb opamp in its day.  The LM358/LM324 (dual / quad) was introduced in 1972 (almost as old) but is more suitable for most tasks that either is suitable for due to it's single supply capability (can use dual supply) and more. || 741 is obsolete and among the honoured dead. 324 is obsolescent but refuses to lie down and die.

Answer (score 0):

Slow op-amps usually consume so little current (<10mA per chip) that you can just use series Schottky diodes to protect the rails. 741s need high supply voltages, so a couple tenths of a Volt dropped across the Schottkys is of no consequence.

Since the Schottkys leak a lot when hot, you'll also want parallel Si diodes to shunt leakage current around the op-amps:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyescd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can always parallel the Schottkys (e.g. four in parallel in place of D1) to lower their voltage drop. Or use higher current-rated Schottkys as they'll have lower voltage drop at the small currents the op-amps usually need.

Comment: Thanks for the advise =), is there a way that I can some sort of overvoltage protection if I wanted to limit to +-15V? I tried adding some zener diodes but it only seems to amplify the voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Your circuit should work as shown.
You MAY have the two FETs swapped and also wrongly connected.

The voltage drop when correct polarity is applied suggests that the FETS are OFF but the body diodes are conducting. This would happen if you (wrongly) has an N channel FET in the high side with source towards Vin, and the opposite for the lower FET.

Note the connection of the FETS - the drain and source are swapped compared to normal use. Source in both cases should be towards load. P channel high, N channel low

Again: High side should be P channel - and the [IRF9530](https://rocelec.widen.net/view/pdf/pggrxej88f/HRISSD80-1.pdf?t.download=true&u=5oefqw)  is. Your results suggest that you have the N channel FET in the high side with source towards Vin. ie FETs swapped AND D & S wrongly connected.